# plotly/python- how to embed newest plot on your website

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I want to include a plot from plotly on my website.

Now I have this: (as from their website)

```
  <iframe  width=750 height=500 frameborder=”0” seamless=”seamless” scrolling=”no” src='https://plot.ly/~zfrancica/66/machine-worn-percenatage/'> </iframe>
```

But I can only get a specific plot.
I call in the backend to generate a new picture every time I refresh the webpage and data may change.

How should I get the newest plot in my account?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you probably need a timer in javascript periodically checks the backend for a new plot

Comment: I knew there is a new plot, but how can I get the index of the plot?src='https://plot.ly/~zfrancica/[[index]]/machine-worn-percenatage/' Do they have an api?